# tab.url.indexOf to check if URL contains specific string in an Extension

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, get

I'm trying to inject a script into a webpage if the current url contains a specific string.

The webpage I'm trying to do this on: `http://s128-en.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=galaxy`

The background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){
    if (tab.status !== "complete"){
        return;
    }
    if(tab.url.indexOf("galaxy") != -1){
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"file": "findtarget.js"});
       console.log("injected");
    }
});
```

For some reason it never injects the script. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script was working just fine. Reloading the extension and reopening the tab fixed this problem.